# XSLT 1.0 - Find text combination in element value recursively

Tags: string, xslt, recursion

I am not able to get this working, so need some help...

My xml looks like

```
<tag>PV1FEPMEDIRSPT530000030412011-04-08OC.CF.QL0000       XXR50067171277HIPAA5010TEST1470000020812011-07-13-13.25.49.846947071320112600003971A1SUPERPSA        SUPERPSA0711201107152011   085                                                                                            90                   KIYEC                                                   M1R50067171277HIPAA5010TEST1470000020812011-07-13-13.25.49.846947071320112600003971A1SUPERPSA        SUPERPSA0711201107152011   085                                                                                            50                                             XIMUK                         </tag>
```

this is actually a  text record wrapped into `<tag/>` elements.

In the above value of tag element, there may be one or more records after the header which has 59 characters. the first record position starts at column 60 and extends upto 360.  The record size is fixed, 300 characters. Subsequent records might appear thereafter.

Need to recursively read the element value at position 60 and 61  (or say for next record 360 and 361) contains 'M1' then look for a position after 221 spaces for an indicator '50'.

checking for first 'M1' indicator and '50' indicator at fixed length is simple, but reading next part of the string becomes difficult as the number of records might be upto 50.

I have a primitive XSL when it matches first record only ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes=" regexp str exsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="regexp str exsl">
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="tag"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="msg">
        <xsl:value-of select="tag/text()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <xsl:call-template name="searchRecursive">
            <xsl:with-param name="msg835" select="$msg"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="m1Indicator" select="60"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="indicator" select="283"/>
        </xsl:call-template>        
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="searchRecursive">
        <xsl:param name="msg835" />
        <xsl:param name="m1Indicator"/>
        <xsl:param name="indicator"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($msg835,$m1Indicator,2) = 'M1' and substring($msg835,$indicator,2) = '50'">
                **test successful**
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="searchRecursive">
                    <xsl:with-param name="msg835" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="m1Indicator" select="$m1Indicator + 300"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="indicator" select="$indicator + 300"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can some one help me extend it further. Thanks!

Comment: THis question is not well-defined at all. First of all you must specify what you want to get as result. then, the string you have provided doesn't have the properties you describe. Please, edit your question and make it logical and understandable!

Comment: Result - I need to route the complete value in the tag element based on the match operation. Routing will be performed by the custom device functions. Text contained in the `<tag/>` element has... 1) a header of 59 characters 2) fixed record size of 300 characters 3) record can start with either XX or M1 4) when a record starts with XX we do not need to look for 50 indicator after 221 spaces 5) first record in this text starts with XX  6) second record (360 column) starts with M1 and has indicator value of 50 after 221 characters 7) there can be upto 50 records (each of 300 character length)

Comment: You need to re-formulate (edit) your question completely and show a complete (but small) example: the string, the rules and the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the correct character offsets, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="tag" name="search">
        <xsl:param name="pRecordIndex" select="55"/>
        <xsl:param name="pStringLength" select="string-length()"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pRecordIndex > $pStringLength"/>
            <xsl:when test="substring(.,$pRecordIndex,2) = 'M1'
                            and
                            substring(.,$pRecordIndex + 223,2) = '50'">
                <xsl:text>**test successful**</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="search">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pRecordIndex"
                                    select="$pRecordIndex + 300"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pStringLength"
                                    select="$pStringLength"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
**test successful**
```

**Note**: Your input has a **54** characters header.

Comment: That was awesome, I could not think in this direction. Thank you!!

Comment: @Liv2luv: You are welcome. Check your input next time, you will get answers faster.